# Possible to program a PIC18F over ICSP without serial clock?

Tags: pic, clock, icsp

I'm playing with a device to see if I can program the PIC with my own code. There is a header and I've traced the pins to the PIC18F, but I notice there is no pin on the header that corresponds to the serial clock (PGC). However, there is one that is connected to RE2/AN7/OESPP (pic below.) Is it possible to program a PIC without the serial clock, or is it possible that RE2/AN7/OESPP can act as the clock line for ICSP?

[image]

Comment: Is the unconnected pin going to an unpopulated component, presumably a 0Ω resistor?

Comment: No, it doesn't appear to be connected to anything. No traces to it on either side, and I probed all points on the circuit with that N/C pin to test for connectivity and nothing.

Comment: Don't think. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57482/using-the-pickit3-and-pic18f4550  https://i.imgur.com/6Myqxp6.png

Comment: Are you sure you've identified those pins correctly? It looks to me like PGC & PGD are both travelling together from pins 16 & 17 on the micro over towards the back of that header. The pin you've labelled "RE2/AN7/OESPP" is where PGC would be if you rotated the package by 90 degrees...

Comment: Opps! You nailed it - I was thinking pin 1 was at top left of Microchip logo like the datasheet is oriented.. I completely missed the pin 1 marker.. so yes, its 90 degrees off. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to program a PIC microcontroller without using a serial clock signal. In-Circuit Serial Programming (ICSP) is a method of programming a PIC microcontroller that allows you to communicate with the microcontroller's internal memory and program it directly, without the need for a separate programming device or external programmer.

To program a PIC microcontroller over ICSP, you will need to connect to the ICSP port on the microcontroller using a suitable programming tool, such as a PICkit or MPLAB X programmer. The programming tool will then send commands and data to the microcontroller over the ICSP lines (MCLR, VPP, PGD, and PGC), allowing you to program the microcontroller's internal memory.

It is not possible to use RE2/AN7/OESPP as the clock line for ICSP programming, as these pins are not designated as the serial clock line. The serial clock line for ICSP programming is typically designated as the PGC line.

Serial pin in you package is PIN9 RB1/AN10/INT1/SCK/SCL (page 5 https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/39632e.pdf)